# how to apply prev on group of rows with same value for column

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

I have data which looks like

| Id | timestamp | customdimension |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 10:00 am | "somedata" |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 10:01 am | "somedata" |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 10:20 am | "somedata" |
| 2 | 1/1/2022 10:05 am | "somedata" |
| 2 | 1/1/2022 10:07 am | "somedata" |
| 2 | 1/1/2022 10:30 am | "somedata" |

I want to group rows with same Id and timestamp within 5 mins of previous row(with same Id). So for any Id drop any rows which comes after > 5mins from the previous row.

expected result (third row for each Id is dropped as it > 5 mins of previous row for that Id)

| Id | timestamp | customdimension |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 10:00 am | "somedata" |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 10:01 am | "somedata" |
| 2 | 1/1/2022 10:05 am | "somedata" |
| 2 | 1/1/2022 10:07 am | "somedata" |

I tried using Prev, but not able to figure out how to bucket rows by Id.

```
requests
| extend PrviousId = prev(Id), timegap = datediff('minute', timestamp, prev(timestamp))
| where timegap < 5
```

this query is not considering by Id, but just by rows. Kindly provide input how to bucket/window rows by Id column and then apply prev.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it:

```
Test
| order by Id asc, timestamp asc 
| extend prevTimestamp = iif(prev(Id) == Id, prev(timestamp), datetime(null))
| where timestamp - prevTimestamp <=5m or isnull(prevTimestamp)
| project-away prevTimestamp
```

| Id | timestamp | customdimension |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 10:00:00.0000000 | "somedata" |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 10:01:00.0000000 | "somedata" |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 10:05:00.0000000 | "somedata" |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 10:07:00.0000000 | "somedata" |

An alternative is to use the partition operator:

```
Test
| partition hint.strategy=native by Id
(
    order by timestamp asc 
    | where timestamp - prev(timestamp) <= 5m or isnull(prev(timestamp))
)
```

| Id | timestamp | customdimension |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 10:00:00.0000000 | "somedata" |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 10:01:00.0000000 | "somedata" |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 10:05:00.0000000 | "somedata" |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 10:07:00.0000000 | "somedata" |

Comment: thanks, avnera, is this the only way (ordering by) to get. here prev is on full data set so prev for fist line of Id==2 ,is record of Id ==1. whereas I want prev only within Id and not acorss Id.s

Comment: Is the concern performance? You can try it with the partition operator (if it does not perform well try the shuffle strategy), see the example in my answer.